# What does exclamation point after variable mean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I've seen in some React/TypeScript implementations such as :

`ref={ ref => this.container = ref! }`

What does the exclamation point means in `ref!`?
Is that something specific in TypeScript, or a new standard JavaScript notation?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

In TypeScript, a postfix `!` removes `null` and `undefined` from the type of an expression.

This is useful when you know, for reasons outside TypeScript's inference ability, that a variable that "could" be `null` or `undefined` actually isn't.

Comment: For reference: this is called the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).