# Variable is used before being assigned with fetch

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript throws the following error on the second last line of my function:

> Variable 'organizationInfoResponse' is used before being assigned.

I am not too sure how to omit that problem since I am assigning the `organizationInfoResponse` inside a try catch block in a fetch. Can you point me in the right direction here please?

```
interface OrganizationInfoResponse {
  organization_name: string;
  organization_id: string;
  errorCode?: string;
}

export const handleGetOrganization = async (
  organizationName: string,
): Promise<OrganizationInfoResponse> => {
  let organizationInfoResponse: OrganizationInfoResponse;

  try {
    const rawRes = await fetch(
      `/sometestendpoint/${organizationName}`,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      },
    );

    organizationInfoResponse = await rawRes.json();

    if (rawRes.status >= 400) {
      if (organizationInfoResponse.errorCode === ErrorCodes.INVALID_ORG_NAME) {
        throw new Error('Given Organization Name is invalid');
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Do something
  }

  return organizationInfoResponse;
};
```

Comment: Try to assign value to organizationInfoResponse like so `let organizationInfoResponse: OrganizationInfoResponse | undefined = undefined`. You are setting the value it try-catch block, so there may be a case when it catches, and then you try to return the value thats was not assigned

Comment: Is that how it should be solved in Typescript or is it 'hacky' way of dealing with those errors.

Comment: I updated the comment and explained the case. It's not a hacky solution :)

Comment: Does that mean I need to update the returned type to `Promise<OrganizationInfoResponse | undefined>`? I can see `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'OrganizationInfoResponse'.` if I don't do that.

Comment: Yes it means exactly this. You need to update return value, because if it catches, undefined is going to be returned

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable 'test' is used before being assigned - Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832316/variable-test-is-used-before-being-assigned-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, you are assigning value to your `organizationInfoResponse` variable inside try-catch block, and then you have return at the end of your function. In case it catches error, your variable will not get any value assigned to it, therefore it cannot be returned. You simply need to assign some value to it on declaration

Answer (score 1):

If there is a scenario where you don't return a valid `OrganizationResponseInfo` and you don't throw an error, you should / would have to change the return type to be nullable. => `Promise<OrganizationResponseInfo?>`

Comment: Or...you return something valid instead of changing the return type.

Comment: Yeah, but if you couldn't fetch it, that wouldn't make a lot of sense...But yeah, theoretically returning a default value would be an option

Comment: [Null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern)

Comment: @VLAZ what exactly do you mean by returning something valid?

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk something that satisfies your type. In your case, some object that is a valid `OrganizationInfoResponse`, for example `{ organization_name: "--NOT FOUND--", organization_id: "" }`